# assembly correct answer for register's value

Tags: assembly

I debugged my assembly application, and I found this in register EDI:

```
EDI = 00000008
```

What's correct answer for question: what's gonna be in register EDI? Should be answer 8 or 8h? (or something else?)

Comment: `8h` is the same as `8`. It's also the same as `100b` or `10` octal. You can use whatever base you want.

Comment: yea, I thought that, thanks. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: I think an ouput of a register value is by default in hex.